# Add a sprite node into a mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit

This is making me feel like a bumbling idiot, and I seem like one by asking this.

I have a board game-like-game where I'm adding spaces (type `DDSpace`'s for each space, a subclass of `NSObject`) to a mutable array (`NSMutableArray`).

Here's the function to load the spaces into the view (`loadSpaces`) so far:

```
NSLog(@"amount of spaces: %i", amountOfSpaces);

for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSpaces; i++) {
    DDSpace *space = [DDSpace new];
    [space setupSpriteWithTheme:gamePlace];
    [spacesArray addObject:space];
}

int num = 0;

// INITIAL SPACE IS SPACE 0.

NSLog(@"adding spaces to scene... self.width = %f, count of space array = %i", self.size.width, spacesArray.count);

for (DDSpace* space in spacesArray) {
    CGFloat x = 100.0 + (num * 225.0);
    NSLog(@"x at num%i = %f.", num, x);
    space.sprite.position = CGPointMake(x, (self.size.width / 3.0));
    space.sprite.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"space%ld",(long)num];

    if (space.sprite.position.x < self.size.width) {
        NSLog(@"adding space.");
        [self addChild:space.sprite];
    }
}

NSLog(@"loadSpaces function finished.");
```

The first game loads 1,000 spaces. The function first logs the amount of spaces to make sure that's set properly (and it is), then it logs the width of the screen and the count of spaces in the array (the array's count is `0`), and then everything below that simply adds the ones that fit onto the screen onto the view.

My goal is to add the spaces to the `spacesArray` array (an `NSMutableArray`) so I can access the other spaces later on, in case a character "takes their turn" (I'll have logic in there to move the others backwards, but to do this, I need an array of spaces).

My question is, **how do I go about adding the `DDSpace`s into the `spacesArray` array?** Is the `addObject:` method correct? Am I simply doing something dumb with it?

None of the spaces appear on the scene, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this before adding objects to it.

```
spaceArray = [NSMutableArray Array];
```

And add objects like this ( like you did )

```
[spacesArray addObject:space];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it would be something silly.